# Why missing terminating " character is a warning?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, compiler-warnings

When, for example,  we compile the following code:

```
printf("hello);
```

we get a warning then an error about the missing `"` character. In my opinion, warnings inform us about a code that can be compiled but whose behaviour may be probably different from what the developper expects. Therefore my comprehension missed up two things:

1. Is there a complete code that can be compiled without errors while containing such a portion of code.
2. If such a code does not exist, why this missing character situation does not give us only an error (not a warning+error).

EDIT (I am doing my best to cope with off-topic votes recommendations):
1. Desired behavior : only one error diagnostic message, there is no need for a warning for the same thing.

2. Other related issues that do not let me accept the first answer:

2.1 Does printf_s() have the same issue? I tried to enable -c11 option with no success.

2.2 The historical reason to emit the warning does not seem to me to be plausible since why this double message was not used too in similar cases (old accepted constructions being forbidden in new c versions).

Comment: Can you show us the warning and the error please.

Comment: main.c 5 warning: missing terminating " character
main.c 5 error: missing terminating " character

Comment: @Mahdaoui7 please [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Comment: If memory serves (and I'm sure I'll be told if otherwise!) very old versions of C allowed multiline literals to be created by simply including the new line inside the quotes. GCC 3.2 allowed it, for example - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Multi-line-Strings.html

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why do you want to know?

Comment: Compilers don't have to give warnings or errors just a diagnostic.  The type and quality of the message is implementation defined.

Comment: GCC give an error : parameter pack allowed after default arguments

Comment: I'm willing to bet there are more errors / warnings that follow as a result of this one.  Please post a full example that others can compile.

Comment: @Steve thank you for your response but even if it was so, now this is not allowed. Hence there is no backward compatibility reason.

Comment: @Mahdaoui7 Then show us the entire code.

Comment: The complete code if it can help #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello);
}

Comment: @Mahdaoui7 [Edit] your question instead of commenting to contain __all relevant information__.

Comment: Are you asking about C or about C++?  These are different languages, although *in this particular case*, I don't think the answer differs between the two.

Comment: @MichaelWalz excuse me but I am new to stackoverflow and I do not kwnow how to conveniently edit a code.

Comment: I've just tried it and I get both a warning and an error. gcc 5.3.0

Comment: @Mahdaoui7 under your question you can see this: "share
edit
close
delete
flag". Just click on "edit" and start editing...

Comment: g++ 4.8.5 emits a warning and an error specifically about the missing quotation mark, and in my particular code, it then emits two more errors.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes the same remark holds for c and c++.

Comment: @Mahdaoui7, you seem to have misunderstood me.  If you *additionally* are asking whether the answer is the same in both C and C++ then do edit your question to say so.  Otherwise, edit it to remove one of the tags [c] and [c++].

Comment: @Mahdaoui7 -- "Hence there is no backward compatibility reason." -- That is what backwards compatibility means. Source code that was legal in previous versions of the Standard should compile on newer implementations.

Comment: The Microsoft VC compiler emits only an error diagnostic message:Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64

source_file.c(6): error C2001: newline in constant

Answer (score 4):

> In my opinion, warnings inform us about a code that can be compiled
>   but whose behaviour may be probably different from what the developper
>   expects. Therefore my comprehension missed up two things:

Your opinion is irrelevant here, and neither the C standard nor the C++ standard distinguish different categories of diagnostic messages.  That many compilers in fact do distinguish is an historically-based convention, albeit a widely observed one.  What ultimately matters is what your compiler means by such a distinction (if indeed it makes one).  On the other hand, and fortunately for you, GCC does adopt a convention similar to what you describe, as documented [in its manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Warnings-and-Errors.html#Warnings-and-Errors):

> - *Errors* report problems that make it impossible to compile your program. [...].
> - *Warnings* report other unusual conditions in your code that may indicate a problem, although compilation can (and does) proceed. [...]

(GCC 7.2 manual, section 13.9; the same or similar text appears also in earlier versions of the manual, back to at least v.4.)

Note well that the documentation frames the meaning of a warning slightly differently than you do: a GCC warning signals that compilation can *proceed*, but there is no assurance that it can complete successfully.  If indeed it ultimately cannot then I would expect GCC, pursuant to its documentation, to also issue an error diagnostic.  That is exactly what I observe with this test program, whether compiling as C or as C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("hello);
}
```

I really think you are making *far* too much of the fact that GCC emits a warning in addition to an error in this case.  That's an implementation quirk of no particular significance.

> 1. Is there a complete code that can be compiled without errors while containing such a portion of code.

It depends on exactly what you mean by that.  Trivially, I could prefix the erroneous line in the above program with `//` to turn it into a comment, and that would make it perfectly valid C and C++ source.  There are manifold other ways I could add to the given source without removing anything to make it valid -- some of them would even produce a program in which a `printf()` call is in fact performed.

I suppose that what you really want to know is whether there is code that would elicit the warning from GCC but not the corresponding error.  To the best of my knowledge, modern GCC does not afford such code, but [historically, GCC *did* allow it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Multi-line-Strings.html) as an extension, in the form of embedded, unescaped newlines in string literals:

```
    printf("hello);
    Goodbye");
```

That behavior was already deprecated in GCC 3.2, and it was removed as early as GCC 4 (current is 7.2).

> 2. If such a code does not exist, why this missing character situation does not give us only an error (not a warning+error).

We can only guess, but it seems plausible that it derives from the historical existence of the language extension described above.  And again, you are making far too much of this.  GCC emits two diagnostics about the same problem -- so what?  The ultimate purpose of the diagnostics is to help you figure out what is or may be wrong with your code, and the diagnostics GCC emits in this case do that job just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. Your guess that I wonder "whether there is a code that would elicit the warning but not the error" is exactly what I meant. However, your reference to the differentiation between errors and warnings claiming that "Errors ... make it impossible to compile and warnings report other .. conditions" just widened my intrigue since in this case the warning does not refer to another condition.

Comment: So the wording of the GCC docs seems slightly inconsistent with its actual behavior in that under some circumstances, it emits both a warning and an error about apparently the same issue in a piece of code.  *Let it go!*  I could probably whip up a justification, but it's not worth the trouble.  This is a non-issue.

Comment: Bolinger thank you very much for your  answer, you are making SO so great.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler probably issues errors when it detects the program is ill-formed, and describes the immediate reason the program failed to be well formed at the location it happened.

This is often useless, because the mistake could have been many lines away.

It also issues warnings that are *guesses* (often educated guesses) what actually caused your problem.  Maybe you forgot a `;` on a previous line, failed to close a `{` or a `(`.  The warning is not "this token is the point of error", but rather "this is where it all went wrong".

In reality, the C++ standard itself does not distinguish between warnings and errors; they are both diagnostics.  It mandates some things cause diagnostics, and does not bar compilers from issuing additional diagnostics.  Compilers are even free to compile ill formed programs with a warning.

I would expect an error for "newline in string", then a warning pointing at the open quote.

Comment: Thank you for your general answer. But what I have not understood is that particular situation. Rephrasing it: what would gcc be missing if it generates only  an error (note that in this particular situation, the warning and the error do state the same thing, are located in the same line and that the actual error is not at many lines away).

Comment: @Mahdaoui7 -- "the actual error is not at many lines away": you need to post your actual code. Read about what is meant by [MCVE]. In any case, as others have said, whether a diagnostic is an error or a warning is _implementation-defined_.